# SQL "Distinct Conditional Rows"

Tags: sql, database, informix

I'm currently struggling with the following problem:

```
|    NAME    |     ID     |
|____________|____________|
     AAA          *NULL*
     AAA           31
     AAA           81 
     BAL          *NULL*
     BDX          *NULL*
     CAL          *NULL*
     CAL           11
```

I want to select each name once under the following circumstances:
- If there's a name with a specified ID -> choose this row
- If there's no id specified (NULL) -> choose this row

So the expected result should be:

```
|    NAME    |     ID     |
|____________|____________|
     AAA           31
     BAL          *NULL*
     BDX          *NULL*
     CAL           11
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Btw: I'm using an Informix DB.

Comment: Solved this by creating an stored procedure.

Comment: You should put your solution in an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, max(id) as id
from your_table
group by name
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I forgot to mention that there will generally be more than 2 ids for every name (see edit) - so the id should be set dynamically in the select statement, which causes the max aggregate doesn't work here.

Comment: So why pick 31 and not 81?

Comment: The id depends on the context (module) executing the sql statement. If theres a context set, select the row with the context id - if no context is set, select the name with id set to null.

Comment: Please be specific in the original question: What is the "context"? What is the "context" so 31 is chosen rather than 81?

Comment: Leave the `MAX` script as it is but just add a `WHERE` clause to specify your context

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. In my application I'm having some cars represented in the database. Every car has a standard name (AAA, CAL, ...). Some cars inherit from other cars - so they're having the same specifications, but a different name. If a inherited car is having another name as its parent, it is listed in the table above. A short example:The name AAA with ID NULL is the standard name - AAA with ID 31 is the name for a inherited car. So if theres a name specified for the car with id 31 I want to select this name, if not select the standard name (id = null). Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Min` will produce the result required (only in current scenario) so you could use both `Min` and `Max` with a case so you're covering both scenarios...

```
select Name, Min(ID) as ID
from your_table
group By Name
```